# comparing pandas list in column with external list

Tags: python, pandas

Given a sample dataframe column:

```
colA           colB
1              [20,40,50,60]
2              [20,70,80]
3              [10,90,100]
```

and given this list  `test_lst = [20, 45, 35]`

I am trying to develop a way to filter my dataframe to only show rows in which at least one value in the list in `colB` is in the `test_lst`

Tried several techniques.  Latest was this one:

```
df[any(x in df['colB'] for x in test_lst)]
```

I am sure some Pandas/Python experts on here have this one at the ready.  I appreciate your time checking out this enigma (at least an enigma to me).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `set.intersection`:

```
test_lst = [20, 45, 35]
print(df[df.colB.apply(lambda x: set(x).intersection(test_lst)).astype(bool)])
```

Prints:

```
   colA              colB
0     1  [20, 40, 50, 60]
1     2      [20, 70, 80]
```

Comment: This solution worked perfectly. I think I can use this in many other ways as well

Answer (score 1):

Or using `isin()`:

```
df[df['colB'].apply(lambda x: pd.Series(x).isin(test_lst).sum()>0)]

   colA              colB
0     1  [20, 40, 50, 60]
1     2      [20, 70, 80]
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to offer this.  I am saving this my snippets folder for future use as well.